# SmtpClient won't authenticate when inflated from web.config

Tags: asp.net, smtpclient

When using the system.net/mail web.config settings to configure my SmtpClient, it fails to deliver emails, with an "protocol error" described best by Base64 encoding and authentication problems:

Example:
With the following Config

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="email@server.com">
            <network host="servermail.outsourced.com"
                     port="2525" 
                     defaultCredentials="false" 
                     userName="username" 
                     password="password"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

And the Code:

```
var tmp = new SmtpClient();

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.Subject = "test";
msg.From = new MailAddress("me@server.com");
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("me@server.com"));
msg.Body = "test";
tmp.Send(msg);
```

Produces the error message:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The server committed a protocol violation The server response was: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException
& exception)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

However, in the following code where I manually set all the properties, the code runs without exception and the email is delivered.

```
var tmp2 = new SmtpClient("servermail.outsourced.com", 2525);
tmp2.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
tmp2.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.Subject = "test";
msg.From = new MailAddress("me@server.com");
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("me@server.com"));
msg.Body = "test";
tmp2.Send(msg);
```

Comment: If you decode UGFzc3dvcmQ6 you get "Password:" so there's a problem with your authentication apparently. I've tested this myself without any problems. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380531/problem-in-sending-mail-with-smtpclient

Comment: That was my initial suspicion, except that the same credentials produce an error when set via the web config, and work when set using code.

Comment: What is the mail server in use?

Comment: were you able to diagnose your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your config settings from within LINQPad against my hMailServer mail server, and they worked great.  So, my guess is that the mail server you are communicating with is handshaking with the client in an unexpected fashion.  When I was testing, I captured the SMTP log from my server, and here's what it looked like (sanitized, of course):

```
SENT: 220 my.mailserv.er ESMTP
RECEIVED: EHLO CLIENTAPP
SENT: 250-my.mailserv.er[nl]250-SIZE 25600000[nl]250 AUTH LOGIN
RECEIVED: AUTH login bWFpbHRlc3RAbXkubWFpbHNlcnYuZXI=
SENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
RECEIVED: ***
SENT: 235 authenticated.
RECEIVED: MAIL FROM:<mailtest@mailserv.er>
SENT: 250 OK
RECEIVED: RCPT TO:<happyuser@mailserv.er>
SENT: 250 OK
RECEIVED: DATA
SENT: 354 OK, send.
```

My server requires SMTP AUTH, and you can see that after my client sends the AUTH command, the server responds with status code 334, and the base-64 encoded representation of `Password:`. So, I'd recommend [turning on the trace functionality](http://systemnetmail.com/faq/4.10.aspx) for the SmtpClient so you can see what is occurring during both scenarios.

I was running LINQPad 4.31, and my linqpad.config file contained:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="mailtest@mailserv.er">
        <network host="my.mailserv.er" port="25" userName="mailtest@mailserv.er" password="supersecure"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

The LINQPad query was as follows:

```
SmtpClient mailer = new SmtpClient();

Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
g.Dump("Message GUID");

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.Subject = "Test:" + g;
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("happyuser@mailserv.er"));
msg.Body = "I HAS A BODY";
mailer.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this for logging

Please comment what AuthenticationModules are used (you'll find them stated in the network.log). 
On my box SmtpLoginAuthenticationModule# is constant used but there are others possible.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Cache">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>

    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="network.log"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>

  </system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the deliveryMethod attribute to force the configuration to use the network-config

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="email@server.com">
            <network host="servermail.outsourced.com"
                     port="2525" 
                     defaultCredentials="false" 
                     userName="username" 
                     password="password"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  It had no effect.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and checking the SMTP server's properties after they have been populated correctly when using web.config to store your credentials? Maybe there's an incorrect value in there.

Answer (score 0):

Guys this code is ok i try using devsmtp for local machine and it work fine

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    Using tmp = New SmtpClient()
        Dim msg As New MailMessage() With {.Subject = "test", .From = New MailAddress("youremail@domain.com")}
        msg.[To].Add(New MailAddress("youremail@domain.com"))
        msg.Body = "test"
        tmp.Send(msg)
    End Using

End Sub
```

please download the devsmtp for local machine from

http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/Release?ProjectName=smtp4dev&DownloadId=269147&FileTime=129575689693530000&Build=20393